# How to detect inside a stream if the subscribe defined an error handler

Tags: rxjs

Suppose I have the following

```
function getData() {
    return this.http.get('data');
}

...

getData().subscribe({
   complete: () => {
      this.closeDialog();
   });
}
```

Not tested, but I think this should work. However, the `this.http` call can throw an error. That can be fixed as follows

```
getData().subscribe({
   error: (err) => { this.showNotification(err) },
   complete: () => { this.closeDialog() }
});
```

or I could catch it inside `getData`

```
 function getData() {
    return this.http.get('data').pipe(catchError(err => {
        return of({});
    });
}
```

What I would like to do is:

1. If the `subscribe` defines an `error` handler, don't catch the error inside `getData`
2. If the subscribe doesn't define an `error` handler, catch the error inside `getData`

Is this possible? If not, I'm all ears to other suggestions/solutions!

Comment: I do not think you can achieve what you are looking for. Consider that an Observable is basically a function whose behavior may be customized by the operators inserted in the `pipe`. So first you declare what the function will do and then, when you invoke `subscribe`, you invoke that function.

Comment: You can do that with proxies (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), but implementation is not trivial at all

Answer (score 0):

> 1. If the subscribe defines an error handler, don't catch the error inside getData
> 2. If the subscribe doesn't define an error handler, catch the error inside getData

I don't understand about point 1, so I will talk about point 2. Well yeah for sure you can do that, in the end RxJS is just Javascript, so you can catch the error using try catch with the help of tap() operators. https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap.